# Add KaTeX math support

Tags: feature-request

Math and software engineering go hand in hand.

Currently, people resort to putting thing like matrices into images, which makes it impossible to copy-paste these matrices to e.g. experiment with them.

Now, I understand that something like MathJax is a heavy dependency for something that will be used by <5% of the answers.

I'd like to propose [KaTeX](https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/) instead. It's very lightweight, and little-overhead for non-math pages if you render it server-side (no extra JS, a small amount of CSS).

An example of a question and answers where this would help tremendously:
[How to transform black into any given color using only CSS filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966641/how-to-transform-black-into-any-given-color-using-only-css-filters)

I realize this has been asked before, but a search for "KaTeX" returns nothing. This proposal is specifically about enabling KaTeX (not mathjax).

Comment: If it's *really* better, perhaps it should be trialed on a mathematical TeX-enabled site instead.

Comment: Re: The server-side rendering part there are [quite a few issues with that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268308/230261), including but not limited to comment and title support, context menu and render engine choices, bandwidth usage, SE's close supporting relationship with MathJax.org, etc. In any case, practicality aside, I agree with above comment that it would make more sense to test somewhere else that already has MathJax enabled and heavily used, and not on SO.

Comment: The question you link to is about MathJax, @JasonC. Is that intentional, are KaTeX and MathJax using the same technology?

Comment: @Makoto: I don't think so: KaTeX does not have full feature parity with MathJax and has some slight differences.

Comment: @JasonC KaTeX is not MathJax. KaTeX has both server-side and browsering rendering capabilities.

Comment: @glebm The point is, server-side rendering of *anything* would have the same fundamental issues. Bandwidth (on everybody's end) being one of the larger ones, as right now there's cache of the client-side rendering scripts everywhere, most notably including end-user browser caching, as opposed to unique images in every post. Plus comment and title support is not feasible server-side, if inline support were to be desired.

Comment: On a different note, all that aside, I don't support the idea of having more than one equation typesetting engine. Potential user-confusion and documentation complications aside, realistically the only end game I can imagine is that if it proves useful, a whole bunch of people making feature requests like "Well math rendering is useful, so can we have MathJax like the other sites?" in which case you might as well just start with MathJax. Or the alternate, albeit less likely, "Why not add KaTeX support to the rest of the sites?" Having two technologies that do the same thing doesn't seem good.